# Exponential Distribution - Probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to figure out the answer to the following question on a past exam given for practice. Since there are no solutions, I was hoping I could get the help needed to figure it out.

---

A BS1300 big-screen TV may die due to screen failure or power supply failure.

The time until power supply failure is exponential with parameter 0.00001.

The time until screen failure is exponential with parameter 0.00002. The time is in hours.

a) Which failure is more probable to occur first?

For this problem, I simply got the expected values and whichever was lower, it should be more probable as the time expected for it to fail was lower.
$E(X) = 100000$ hours for power supply, $E(X) = 50000$ hours for screen failure. Therefore, screen is more likely to fail first.

b) What is the probability that a BS1300 will die within 10000 hours?

PS = power supply, SF = screen failure
$P(PS = 10000) = 0.000016374 P(SF = 10000) = 0.000025422$. If we add it up, we get PS or SF $= 0.000025422$.

c) If the BS1300 is known to be dead, what is the probability that its power supply failed?

Part c), I'm not sure how to figure this out. I tried drawing a venn diagram but I'm unsure how to do it for exponential. Help would be appreciated on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :  Here is the edited solution:

Ist part is correct

2nd Part

x1 - time until failure happens with power supply

x2 - time until failure happens with screen failure

Define x1 be the R.V with pdf = f(x1) = $\lambda_1$*$e^{-\lambda_1*x1}$

Define x2 be the R.V with pdf = f(x2) = $\lambda_2$*$e^{-\lambda_2*x2}$

P(X1<=10000) = $1-e^{-\lambda_1*x1}$ ............(1)

P(X2<=10000) = $1-e^{-\lambda_2*x2}$ ............(2)

Computing these two we get

(1) = 0.09516

(2) = 0.18126

Probability that the machine will fail = Max(0.09516,0.18126)

Another property of exponential distribution that is derived  is

If X1 and X2 are independent exponential RVs with parameters λ1 and λ2,

P(X1 < X2) = $\frac{λ_1}{λ_1 + λ_2}$

P(X1 < X2) essentially encapsulates the fact that the time until failure due to power supply precedes the time until failure due to Screen Failure is indeed the probability that the failure is due to power supply.

MoonKnight:  I thought about your comment and realized that two CDFs will approach 1 as move to the extreme right on time. So I refrain from using that argument.  But I would have liked to see you completed solution with your reasoning.

Thanks

Satish

Comment: Oh, we didn't learn about Bayes theorem this term, unless I missed that lecture. Since this is last years exam, maybe it was cut out this term and left for the next stats class. Edit: Seems like we did talk about it, but not in that form. Our professor simply showed us the conditional probability formula and said we won't be using Baye's but this is a simple or other form of it.

Comment: See the edited solution and it makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

(a) correct

(b) wrong, first of all here you should use the CDF but not the PDF. Also you cannot simply add them up.

PG for power good, SG for screen good.
$P(PG)=1-p(PS)$, $P(SG)=1-P(SF)$.

BS1300 is not dead, equivalent to both PG and SG. Since PG and SG are independent.

So $P(PG\cap SG)=P(PG)P(SG)=...$

Comment: In the second part, it only talks about Failure so I thought that it would suffice, if he finds P(Failure/PS) and P(Failure/SF) and using total probability all he has to do is add them up.  The third part is a clear usage of Bayes theorem.  Now that he found these two probabilities, he will find the probability of failure due to Power failure.  Part 3 is related to Part 2.  I agree with you on using CDF not pdf.

Comment: @satishramanathan, First of all he seems to only use the larger one rather than actually add them up. Second of all you cannot simply add them up. If the probablity of screen failure at time $t$ is 0.6 and the probability of power supply failure at the same time is 0.5, the probability of BS1300 is dead at time $t$ cannot be 1.1

Comment: The problem statement is the failure can only happen due to Power supply or Screen Failure.  In which case P(Failure/SF)+P(Failure/PS)+P(Success/SF)+P(Success/PS) = 1 inspite of the fact that the failure due to different modes are characterised by different lambdas

Comment: Well, Your P(Failure/SF) is different from the definition given in the problem. The CDF of both exponential distribution (SF and PS) clearly approaches one when your used it for 10^10 hours. Do you still think P(Failure/SF)+P(Failure/PS)+P(Success/SF)+P(Success/PS) = 1?

Comment: @satishramanathan So your P(Failure|SF) is not the CDF of exponential distribution for Screen Failure. It is actually P(Failure|SF)=$P(SF\cap PG)=P(SF)(1-P(PS))$

Comment: Please see the edited solution

Comment: Thanks, forgot I should be using the CDF as it's within 10K hours, not exactly 10K.